# Why is the request body empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple View like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <select id="myList" style="width: 50%">
        @for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            <option value="@i">Item @i</option>
        }
    </select>

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And the corresponding actions

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? myList)
{
    Debugger.Break();

    return View();
}
```

When I click the *Submit* button, though, the request body, as seen in inspectors such as Firebug and Fiddler, and also as reported by the `myList` parameter of the `Index` action, is empty.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the select element a `name` attribute.

```
<select id="myList" name="myList" style="width: 50%">
```

Comment: Oh, yes. I just remembered while you were typing your answer.

Comment: And what if I also wanted to pass both, the text the user types (he may not select out of the list, I am using a widget) along with the value?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 make sure the textbox he's entering into also has a name, you can figure it out by using inspect html in Chrome.

Comment: Hmm! Neat. Thank you.